# Goals in Google Analytics do not work

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I cannot figure out how to get Google Analytics Goals to work:

URL in Google Analytics report:

/relay/v2/relay.cgi/www.mydomain.com/faerdig.php?tid=3414528&orderid=03-14:29&amount=100000&cur=208&date=20101003&time=1430&cardnopostfix=4000&timer=03-14:29&cardid=2&transfee=0

(Above URL is taken straight from the Google Analytics report)

**I want to search for:** faerdig

I have tried the following:

**Head Match:** /relay/v2/relay.cgi/www.mydomain.com/faerdig

**Regular Expression Match:** faerdig

Comment: It can take up to 24 hours for a goal result to be visible in Analytics. Have you left it this long?

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost GA has a delay of 24-48 hours on custom coding (and sometimes even generic page view hits), so don't expect to see hits instantly.

2nd, you must have the global GA code on the target page in order for it to be tracked in GA.  Have you ensured that the global code is on the actual page?  Pointing to the right account, etc...?